# AC current existing on cable company Cable TV / Internet Coaxial Cable

Tags: electrical, internet

Is AC current on Cox Cable Coaxial cable (cable TV/Internet service) something I need to get fixed?.

Using a Fluke 322 clamp meter I measure 0.02 amperes AC reading on the COX coaxial cable, measured at the point where the cable exits the inner wall of my house.  I get 0.00 - 0.01 amperes on the downstream side of the 3-way coaxial signal splitter (two TVs, and an Internet cable modem). The variance in measurements may be due to meter accuracy.

Using the clamp meter I measure 0.35 amperes AC on the Cox cable coaxial cable immediately upstream of the entrance box (outside the house).  Additionally, the ground wire from the cable entrance box shows 0.28 - 0.31 amperes AC.  This ground wire (solid copper AWG 10 or 12) connects to the household grounding electrode system which consists of three (3) properly sized grounding electrodes connected (bonded) together and spaced at 6 foot intervals.  The ground wire run from the cable entrance to the ground rod connection is approximately 50 feet.  The Cox cable in my neighborhood is underground.  By the way, I ran the grounding wire from the coax outside entry point as the cable company had not grounded the cable at the house entrance.

It appears that most of the current from the Cox cable coaxial cable is bleeding off onto the ground wire.

This Issue is similar to the issue, subject: AC Voltage on Coaxial Cable (Cable TV)
at: [AC Voltage on Coaxial Cable (Cable TV)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/83049/ac-voltage-on-coaxial-cable-cable-tv/203793#203793)

Comment: Why did you decide to check it? What is the problem you are having that needs fixing? That's like less than 3 watts... I would guess that with an *amp* meter that reading might fall within the accuracy margin of error. Check the meter manual.

Comment: Turn on a big load like a heater-fan, hair dryer, microwave etc. and check again. Did the number change significantly?

Comment: Yes, turn on some big 120V loads and see if the number moves.  Also, have you checked to make sure your coax grounding block is properly connected to the mains grounding system in your house?

Comment: that's 20 mA short circuit current ... how much current do you measure when you place your finger in the circuit?

Comment: After you stick your finger in a socket as jsotola asks can you hold the clamp meter on your finger while standing on 1 foot under the power lines and provide us with that reading,,, not kidding try it or another body part and a .02 reading might be low,,,

Comment: @EdBeal  Couldn't help but laugh at your response.   Yeah, checking for power by "feel" is never a good idea!

Comment: @EdBeal That's really much better to do with a cat you're not particularly fond of.

Comment: The Cox Cable coax grounding block is properly connected to the house grounding system per NEC as noted in my initial question. Something Cox Cable failed to do.

The issue is- why is an ac current measured on cable service coax, and is this smething to be concerned with?

As for messrs jstola & Beal-  You guys sound like some old-time electrician I've seen checking load center circuits by licking his fingers and touching the fuse connections to see if the circuits were hot. He lived, so his technique may be a good field check- eh?

Comment: Update to my initial question.  FYI, I found the followng explanation about why ac current may flow on residential CATV cable service.

Comment: FYI, Explanation on ac current on cable service.  https://www.dps.ny.gov/gbcs_Comments_Questions_and_Answers.html     Where conventional CATV service coaxial cable is grounded and bonded to a building grounding electrode system, a part of which is the electrical service ground, a current will flow in the coaxial cable sheath if power is being used in the dwelling and if the dwelling power load is not balanced.   ... staff found sheath currents above 3 amps in some instances. Average was approximately 0.25 amps, with low readings in the area of 0.1 amp & high reading approaches 0.7 to 0.8 amps.